# Searching for better multitype validation

Tags: php, validation

I need to check if variable is of specified scalar type - but I cannot use general function like is_scalar - because this would accept also those types (that type) I don't want to accept.

It is possible to check types step by step:

- with in-built functions like `is_string`
- with separate comparation of value given by `gettype`

but it is a bit incomfortable because it would give a very long code.

So, I prepared following (relatively short - if you ignore *external* parts) code:

`!in_array(gettype($Item), MarC::Show_Options_Scalars())`

where

function `Show_Options_Scalars()` represents allowed accepted scalar types.

That one prepares array of allowed types - from constants written in interface. That is why I wrote that own validation is relatively short if you ignore *external* parts.

**And still I am not sure if multitype validation could be done better** - it means if can I validate variable type by else better way. That *external* code is not reason why search for better multitype validation.

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: Your question is still not clear. Perhaps read it aloud to a friend and see if it makes sense to them.

Comment: Do you allow a string to contain an int (such as `"42"`)? Or do you also want to filter those kind of values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i like your code. i would only make a function for it

```
 function val( &$value ) {
    return !in_array( gettype( $value ), array( 'boolean', 'integer', 'what ever' ) );
 }
```

I use & to save some res.

useage:

```
if( val( $test ) ) die( 'pass' );
```

Comment: Encapsulating into function is possible, but it has not a much of sense, when function (`Show_Options_Scalars()` for example) returns me an array with _legal_ types.

Comment: Then i cant understand your aim. You can chose different var types and you can replace the array with your function. There is no possibility to make the code shorter in your usage.

Comment: I don't ask for changes of my code - but for alternatives available elsewhere.

Comment: And pardon, sometimes I don't know what to get until I get it. Your way is better - but I would not use `&`.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I totally understand your question. But.

The following function will allow you to input both your variable and your 'legal' types array.

```
function validate($input, $allowed_types) {
    return in_array(gettype($input), $allowed_types);
};
```

So,

```
validate('a great string which is a scalar!', ['string', 'float', 'blah']);
```

Will return `true`. While:

```
validate('a great string which is a scalar!', ['integer', 'float', 'blah']);
```

Will return `false`.